# Cannot run android aplication - appcompat_v7 not found -

Tags: android, eclipse

Im trying to build a app using eclipse juno as IDE, and I've installed here 4.2.2, 7.0 and 2.3.3 API's. Browsing here, I found some similar problems, but I've a new one.

Some people told to download on SDK the Android Support Repository (already done here). If i go to Projects -> Properties -> Android, i cannot found any library here.

In my SDK folder(extras/android), there's no other folder here (just one folder called m2repository) and should've one called appcompat_v7.

Comment: Why are you still using Eclipse it's been deprecated since 2015 June

Comment: I would suggest Android Studio for developing Android Projects. ADT for Eclipse is no longer maintained or supported by Google. Moreover you've interesting features in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using Eclipse and start using [Android studio V2.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?gclid=CJXI4em5rM8CFUoWaAodXrcD5w) (latest stable release) and include the Appcompact in the Gradle file like the way I have mentioned below.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```